# Neo4j Cypher query: Sum the results of two queries

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where I have  the following structure:

[image: Sample graph]

**Nodes:**

1. *Page*(BLUE) -> Page is attached to the lectureseries node and lecture by ownerof relation.
2. *Lecture Series*(PURPLE)-> Lectureseries connected to lecture by seriesof relation
3. *Lecture* (GREEN)-> lecture connected to page and lectureseries as mentioned above. lecture have property as public, follower, private and privilege
   One of the lecture i.e lect1 is connected to the user by a realtion privileged.
4. *User* (RED) (here named Ann) - It is connected to page by follows relation and to 1 lecture mentioned above.

**Initial Condition:**

We have to show the user all the public and follower lecture always for that we have the perfect query with no problem we get the required result.

```
MATCH
  (o:page{name:'engg'})-[r:ownerof]-(n:lectureseries)-[s:seriesof]-(l:lecture)
WHERE l.privacy='public' or l.privacy='follower'
RETURN DISTINCT n.name as name,n.series_name as title, COUNT(l) AS lecturecount
```

**Result:**

```
name    lecturecount

java    2 (lect3, lect4)
```

**Problem:** Now, we have to add those lecture in the count that if the privilege lecture is connected to the user by the relation **privileged**

I tried this query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (o:page {name:'engg'})-[r:ownerof]-(n:lectureseries)-[s:seriesof]-(l:lecture)
WHERE l.privacy='public' or l.privacy='follower'
RETURN DISTINCT n.name as name, COUNT(l) AS lecturecount
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (o:page {name:'engg'})-[r:ownerof]-(n:lectureseries)-[s:seriesof]-(l:lecture)-[:privileged]-(u:user {name:'Ann'})
RETURN DISTINCT n.name as name, COUNT(l) AS lecturecount
```

**Results:**

```
name    lecturecount

java    2

java    1
```

But the result should be a single line: java, 3

I searched a lot, ended up to the `UNION` clause, but it's not helping.

**NEW PROBLEM:**

How to sum up the *result as*

```
seriesname  lecturecount             seriescount    lecturecount

java    2                      AS      2             3
dotnet  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I crafted an example dataset based on your figure. (Tip: you can export a CSV from the Neo4j web UI and include it in the question.)

```
CREATE
  (lect1:lecture {name:"lect1"}),
  (lect3:lecture {name:"lect3", privacy: "public"}),
  (lect4:lecture {name:"lect4", privacy: "follower"}),
  (lect5:lecture {name:"lect5"}),
  (engg:page {name:"engg"}),
  (Ann:user {name:"Ann"}),
  (java:lectureseries {series_name:"java"}),
  (engg)-[:ownerof]->(lect1),
  (engg)-[:ownerof]->(lect3),
  (engg)-[:ownerof]->(lect4),
  (engg)-[:ownerof]->(lect5),
  (Ann)-[:follows]->(engg),
  (Ann)-[:privileged]->(lect1),
  (java)-[:seriesof]->(lect1),
  (java)-[:seriesof]->(lect3),
  (java)-[:seriesof]->(lect4),
  (java)-[:seriesof]->(lect5),
  (engg)-[:ownerof]->(java)
```

Query:

```
MATCH (:page {name:'engg'})-[:ownerof]->(n:lectureseries)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:seriesof]->(l1:lecture)
WHERE l1.privacy='public' or l1.privacy='follower'
WITH n, COUNT(l1) as lecturecount1
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:seriesof]->(l2:lecture)<-[:privileged]-(:user{name:'Ann'})
RETURN n.series_name as name, lecturecount1 + COUNT(l2) AS lecturecount
```

The [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-with) construct allows you to chain queries together.

Results:

```
╒════╤════════════╕
│name│lecturecount│
╞════╪════════════╡
│java│3           │
└────┴────────────┘
```

A couple of remarks:

- Use directed edges in the query. It does not have a great impact performance-wise but it improves readability.
- You don't have to name variables that you are not using later. For this reason, I dropped the `o` and `r` variables.
- According to the Cypher [styleguide](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/docs/style-guide.adoc), all keywords should be uppercase.
- Unless you have multiple `ownerof` edges between a page and its lecture series, there is not need to use `DISTINCT`.
- Make sure that you carry node `n` in the `WITH` clauses, else you'll get a new `n` variable in the following matches (Thanks InverseFalcon.)

Comment: Be careful with WITH and preserving the scope of variables from earlier parts in the query. Your OPTIONAL MATCHes are matching on the variable `n`, but `n` is not in scope because it isn't being brought along in your WITHs...`n` is instead binding to anything connected by `:seriesof` relationship to lectures, and it just works out okay because there is only one `:lectureseries` in your example dataset.

Comment: @Gábor Szárnyas Thanks alot. It helped me totally.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW PROBLEM:** -Solved myself posted for others who may stuck like me.

```
Match (o:page{name:'engg'}) 
with o 
optional match (o)-[:ownerof]-(ls:lectureseries)-[:seriesof]-(l:lecture) 
where l.privacy='public' or l.privacy='follower' 
with o ,count(distinct(ls)) as lscount,count(l) as lecount
optional match (o)-[:ownerof]-(ls)-[:seriesof]-(l1:lecture)-[:privileged]-(u:user{name:'Ann'})
RETURN lscount as lectureseriescount,lecount+count(l1) as lecturecount
```